# How do I add a tag to a question that someone else asked?

Tags: support, tags

How do I add a tag to a question that someone else asked? He would get support form first party by tagging it correct. Now I am trying to earn some badges my score by adding the tags for him. Is it even possible and if it is, are there any badges for this ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just hit on the edit link available under the question post and you'll see the tags listed. You can then add/remove them.

It'll go through a review before it gets approved though; so try to include a nice brief description of why you added/changed the tags.

---

The links are shown just below tags:

[image: webmasters]

I used webmaster SE for this purpose. With 500+ rep you get a separate `retagging` option.

Comment: Just found out by myself, thx anyway - hope this will help someone else sometime :)

Comment: If you hover over the tags, the in-place "edit tags" option shows up.  That allows you to edit tags without editing the question.

Comment: @Andomar That's for 10k and above rep users :P

Answer (score 1):

The privilege of retagging requires [500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions).

Comment: just adding a tag worked with having less, but it is under revision now. maybe for delete or to retag without revision...